# How to create one to many relation that will be updated?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following entities with relation **one to many** - one `folder` can have many `files`.

```
folder
{
    string id;
    string name;
    string owner;
}

file
{
    string id;
    string name;
}
```

How can I create this relation by taking into consideration the following rules?

- The `folder` is a separate entity, which can be updated or displayed on its own, so **it can't be** part of the `file` document, it **must** remain in separate collection.
- When I query all the the `files`, I want them to be sorted by the `folder.name`. This query must have pagination.
- I want to display only `files` that are in `folders` owned by the caller.

As I don't want to use join in document database, and I want to get all the data in one query, I was thinking about copying the `folder` document in the `file`:

```
file 
{
    string id;
    string title;
    Folder folder;
}
```

This way, I can query by including all the listed rules. And I think this would be perfect solution, if the `folder` name was static, but the `folder.name` is something that the user can update. And if the `folder.name` is updated, the relation in the `file` will remain with invalid/old data.
So, what is the correct approach in this situation? Should I implement a mechanism for updating the relation ones the `folder.name` is updated?

**Update**:
I am expecting, a lot of queries for listing of the `file`s, and less updates of the `folde.name`s. The most important think for me, is that I need a design that will allow me to query, sort and use pagination on the `files` collection. So, at this point I am researching what are the options with their pros and cons.

Comment: You know there is [updateMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) right?  There is never a perfect solution in Mongo, it's always a balance between optimising something with some trade offs.  If you embed folder into a file you optimise queries by avoiding lookups. The trade offs are you spend more storage, you slow down updates, you risk inconsistent results during the updates unless you use transactions. You need to consider size of your data set and query patterns to answer the question.

Comment: Yes, I know. As I don't fully understand the document database design, the question sounds not concreate enough. I will try to update it. Thank you for the comment, Alex.

Comment: It is too vague to the SO standards I'm afraid. Check https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 it's almost a decade old, yet it reflects the spirit of the DB and ideas behind its concept.  Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72164834/mongodb-schema-design-when-to-use-the-extended-reference-pattern-vs-relying-on/72166068#72166068 to understand what controls you should measure to make a grouded decision.